# Will my student insurance in US, as an international student cover my pre-existing ileostomy caused due to Crohn's disease?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, united-states, international-students

I am planning on applying abroad for my further studies. But I have this disease called Crohn's, due to which currently I am having an ileostomy. Few of the costs associated with ileostomy are I need to buy accessories to maintain my ileostomy. And also I would need to take medication for my Crohn's, which I heard are quite costly abroad. So my question is:

1) Will the student insurance that the University collects help me with the accessories and the medications required?

2) Also, if at all I am eligible for the insurance, if something were to happen to me abroad(like an emergency surgery due to my pre-existing condition) would I have to pay for it from my pocket?

3) I heard that health care system in US is quite brutal. So is there any other country you would probably suggest for me to pursue my studies.

Correct me if I am wrong about the idea of health care. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Student insurance is not really that different from employer insurance so I am not sure that this is really a question related to academia. I am not sure there is a site where it is on topic (I don't think it fits at health.se).

Comment: I don't think any SE site can answer this, especially for your specific set of questions. What exactly is covered by your insurance will depend on your insurance. Since this is likely to be a substantial issue for you, you'll have to address it with universities you are interested in applying to. At public universities, insurance is often the same as the insurance that state employees get, which has historically been quite good for the US, but in some places (like my state) has gotten much worse lately.

Comment: Some insurances will not cover existing conditions so that may be an issue anyway...

Comment: The simplest answer is no, don't come to the US if you have a chronic health condition.

Comment: Health care for students is highly dependent on the institution. As one data point, my daughter's institution requires that she be covered by insurance herself or through us (her parents) - they have no insurance plan and no infirmary.

Answer (score 2):

You will find that insurance in the US isn't nearly as comprehensive as that of many other countries. Neither is there any universal health system in the US. So, this is a question that you need to explore separately with each university you might attend.

My best guess, however, is that you will be disappointed most places. In the absence of clear statements from individual universities, assume the worst.

Europe, including some non EU countries have good coverage, but even there you need to know whether it is available to non-citizen residents and students. It will vary, but the chances there seem better.

But, to be clear, the health *care* system is quite good: doctors and such. It is the health *insurance* system that is brutal, and the two are quite distinct.